# Gmail API: Retrieve the message in HTML and scrape it

Tags: android, email, gmail, gmail-api

I've implemented the Gmail REST API. I want to retrieve the emails in the raw html format not as a JSON as I want to scrape it. What are the ways in which I can do this.

PS: I'm on android.

Comment: why you want to scrap if api is avail there

Comment: Because I want only certain parts of the email. I do not want all of it. I just need to extract a link from it and a table. @ashutiwari4

Comment: so you can perform operations over String